# What's the best way to pass data from multiple tables/one database to a view?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm running into a weird issue. I'm using MVC 4, and I'm trying to pull data from two separate tables to pass into my view. Normally I'd just build a model to handle this, but these two tables are already used in other models, so when I try to create a *new* model, there's issues with ambiguity.

I guess my question is this: what's the best way to pull data from two separate tables on a database and get it into a view? For some reason, the whole concept of Entity Framework is a little confusing to me, so maybe I'm missing something simple here.

Also, if anyone has any place where I can read up on some pretty comprehensive database interactions using EF, I'd really appreciate it (though I guess I could just google that)

Comment: Suggest doing a bit of research around the repository pattern and data access layers. You could, for example, write a service class that queries your db (either via a repository or some other mechanism) which returns a model (known as a DTO or data transfer object) which is then transformed to a viewmodel in your controller.

Comment: Interesting; I wasn't aware that type of thing existed. I'll look it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way will be to create a ViewModel and add the 2 models inside of it.

So you will need to create something like

```
public class MyViewModel
{    
    public MyFirstEntity FirstEntity{ get; set; }
    public MySecondEntity SecondEntity{ get; set; }
}
```

And in your controller do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int someparameter)
{
    MyFirstEntity firstEntity=
        BusinessLogic.GetMyFirstEntity(someparameter);
    MySecondEntity secondEntity=
        BusinessLogic.GetMySecondEntity(someparameter);

    MyViewModel myViewModel = new MyViewModel 
    {           
        FirstEntity = firstEntity,
        SecondEntity= secondEntity
    };

    return View(myViewModel);
}
```

Also you can check [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/01/26/view-models-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) for more information on the matter.

Comment: Eh, this is probably what I'm looking for. I'll look into it. Thanks, friend!

Answer (score 2):

Typically, your view model would only pass the view the information it requires. If implemented correctly, the view model should not know or care where the information has comes from.

In your case, you would create the view model based upon the data from the two tables, rather than using the two tables themselves.

The following is an example of what you could do:

```
public ViewResult MyActionMethod()
{
    var tableOne = MyDataRepository.GetDataFromTableOne();
    var tableTwo = MyDataRepository.GetDataFromTableTwo();

    var model = new MyActionMethodModel()
    {
        Property1 = tableOne.Property1,
        Property2 = tableTwo.Property2,
    };

    return this.View(model);
}
```